# If isset not working properly after condition is successful

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, isset

I have a form which posts information to one table and a picture to a second table with a foreign key from the first table, both inserts are successful, but my redirect statement isn't...

This is the PHP code:

```
if (isset($_POST['btn-save'])) {
        $itemname = $_POST['title'];
        $price = $_POST['price'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];
        $city_city_id = $user->getcityID($_POST['city']);
        $category_category_id = $user->getcategoryID($_POST['category']);
        $user_user_id = $_SESSION['userSession'];
        if ($user->newItem($itemname, $price, $description, $city_city_id, $category_category_id, $user_user_id)) {
            if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {
                $image = file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
                $item_item_id = $user->lastInsertID();
                if ($user->newImage($image, $item_item_id)) {
                    header("Location: sellitem.php?inserted");
                }
            } else {
                header("Location: sellitem.php?failure");
            }
        }
    }
```

These are both functions used:

```
public function newItem($itemname, $price, $description, $city_city_id, $category_category_id, $user_user_id) {
    try {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO item(itemname,description,price,city_city_id,category_category_id,user_user_id) VALUES(:itemname, :description, :price, :city_city_id, :category_category_id, :user_user_id)");
        $stmt->bindparam(":itemname", $itemname);
        $stmt->bindparam(":description", $description);
        $stmt->bindparam(":price", $price);
        $stmt->bindparam(":city_city_id", $city_city_id);
        $stmt->bindparam(":category_category_id", $category_category_id);
        $stmt->bindparam(":user_user_id", $user_user_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        return true;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
}

public function newImage($image, $item_item_id) {
    try {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO picture(image,item_item_id) VALUES(:image, :item_item_id)");
        $stmt->bindparam(":image", $image);
        $stmt->bindparam(":item_item_id", $item_item_id);
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: try adding `return true` in function `newImage` in try condition..it should work..

Comment: note: testing `$_FILES['image']` is **NOT** a valid test for a successful upload. all that'll tell you is if an upload was *attempted*. You need to check `$_FILES['image']['error']`. Plus, you're simply assuming the query will never fail. That's not a good way to code things. You need to explicitly test return values or try/catch.

Comment: no error, it justs does everything thats supossed to do but it doesnt redirect me to 'sellitem.php?inserted'

Comment: Check your PHP log for a warning about "Headers already sent". Make sure your page doesn't produce any output before it calls `header()`.

Comment: `dump` the `$_FILE` variable and see what it contains before checking `if` condition on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You include this line:

```
if ($user->newImage($image, $item_item_id))
```

Which PHP evaluates as:

```
if ($user->newImage($image, $item_item_id) == true)
```

This means the [return value](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php) of `newImage` needs to evaluate as true. But, your function is only returning a value in case of error when it returns `false`. Edit the function to include a return value in the success case as well:

```
public function newImage($image, $item_item_id) {
    try {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO picture(image,item_item_id) VALUES(:image, :item_item_id)");
        $stmt->bindparam(":image", $image);
        $stmt->bindparam(":item_item_id", $item_item_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        return true;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
}
```